# Error running on iOS simulator with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to set up flutter on Mac (macOS Sierra). I am trying to run one test application as per installation instruction I am getting an error as below

> === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

```
/Users/apple/work/flutter/my_app/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:8:65: error:
** **
'LaunchOptionsKey' is not a member type of 'UIApplication'

    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:

    [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
```

Flutter doctor summary:

```
$flutter doctor
```

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.12.6 16G1510,
locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 9.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
```

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have? If it's an old version have you tried going to the latest?

Comment: I changed the UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey to UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey and its working but still wondering why this happened automatically by flutter.

Comment: Changing UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey to UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey seems the only option right now. In a future version, it might be resolved.

Answer (score 4):

In AppDelegate.swift, Use UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey instead of UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Flutter 1.12, `UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey` is (the only) working solution